# Redirect to a webpage using an attribute in Asp.net webforms with web.api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, attributes

I created this attribute class to redirect to a web page url:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;
using UtilityLibrary;

namespace xxxxxxx.Web.Attributes
{

    public class SessionExpireWebApiFilterAttribute : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public string UrlPortal { get { return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Portal"].ToString(); } }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext filterContext)
        {    
            try
            {                 
                if (StateManager.Instance.Get(Key.Autenticacao, State.Session) == null)
                {                        
                    filterContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.RedirectMethod);
                    filterContext.Response.Headers.Location = new Uri(http://www.examplepage.com);

                }

                base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {    
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but nothing happens, the method that i used the attribute didn't excecute, but the page completed the post as status 200! Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Looks you are using OnActionExecuting, it is called before action method. Use OnResultExecuting or OnResultExecuted.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute.onresultexecuting(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: Ok, but i need the attribute execution before actionresult. I need to validate session and redirect to home if the session ends and I need it on webapi controller.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i'm did mistake. 
I think you can do:

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{ 
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(url);
    return;   
 }
```

i think this fix in your code will be help your.
        public class SessionExpireWebApiFilterAttribute : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
        {
            public string UrlPortal { get { return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Portal"].ToString(); } }

```
        public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext filterContext)
        {    
            try
            {                 
                if (StateManager.Instance.Get(Key.Autenticacao, State.Session) == null)
                {                        
                    filterContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.RedirectMethod);
                    filterContext.Response.Headers.Location = new Uri(http://www.examplepage.com);
                    /*add this return*/return;
                }

                base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {    
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```